# important is not applying changes in css in google chrome

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In my website, there is a main.css file, and bootstrap.css file, there are some css codes that are present in both files, I tried to change one of them (in the bootstrap.css) and I wrote !important beside it. In firefox, the change was applied and the !important one was considered. While in chrome, the other one (in the main.css) without the !important was considered.
Anyone knows why's that?!

In main.css :

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: white;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    color: #222222;
}
```

In bootstrap.css :

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #2b3062 !important;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: transparent;
}

What's the problem here?
```

Comment: Something is so weird in my code! 
I tried to delete the css code from main.css ! And it's still not applying any change.. and in inspect element in google chrome, the main.css code is still shown!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked just by pressing (ctr+f5) ! It refreshed the current stylecheet.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any Chrome-specific error that could be causing this. Have you tried checking the developer console (right-click and inspect element)? It should show you a styles panel where you can see whether any styles overwrite your styling. If nothing else works, you could always try adding an inline style to the :

`<a style="color: #2b3062"> ... </a>`

This will automatically overwrite any style sheets.

Have you tried quitting Chrome (maybe restarting the computer) or clearing the cache? Maybe Chrome cached the old version of the style sheet.

Comment: i will try restarting computer

Comment: I restarted chrome, then restared the computer, nothing changed..
The same style that I've deleted from main.css is still there in the inspect element in chrome! with the same old number of line ..

Comment: It worked just by pressing (ctr+f5) ! It refreshed the current stylecheet..